# Unknown amplifier circuit Analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, schematics, active-filter

Does anyone know what this kind of amplifier circuit is? I am trying to analyze it by calculating its gain, cut-off frequency, and frequency response. I am not sure how to break this circuit into different parts by working on transfer function or general amplifier analysis, as part of the RC circuit is in the loop of the amplifier and it really looks like a second-order active low pass filter but with one extra capacitor which may greatly change the functionality. I am also new to simulating any circuit on the computer. What are the effective tools people use nowadays? The analysis may be less handy with using some simulators.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTM9Lt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I see an input passive high-pass RC (1st order), loaded down by a 3rd order active filter, and followed by yet another passive low-pass RC (1st order.) Is that what you also see? The leading high-pass may be considered to be a DC-blocking capacitor, with a necessary weak DC galvanic connection to ground. C19 is there to stabilize the opamp against oscillation, I imagine. So you could examine the active circuit as 2nd order, I believe. But without doing the calcs, I'm not sure.

Comment: See this https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/basic-linear-design/chapter8.pdf page 8.72 and after ... fig 8-49 and 8-67

Comment: LTSpice is one freely available program which you could use to simulate this.

Comment: As @jonk stated, it's basically a series of cascaded filters - DC block, active (band reject?), and an output low pass. If you told us the origin or application, that might be helpful. Looks to be designed for rather low frequency use (the output filter has a -3dB point of 96Hz, and the HF rolloff R20/C19 is set about 1.6kHz).

Comment: The middle stage is called a Sallen-Key-Filter / topology.

Comment: @danmcb CircuitLab is built into Electronics Stack Exchange, and includes a circuit simulator good enough to sweep this simple filter. OP could have essentially answered their own question just by drawing the circuit using the tool built into this site ;)

Comment: @danmcb It's a part of the circuit for EEG. The cutoff frequency at Vo does make sense with the application, as EEG would be up to 100 Hz and down from 0.1 Hz.  The fc of the passive high pass filter is around 0.16Hz.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Theory

> What are the effective tools people use nowadays?

The first, most effective, and primary tool to use is your brain.

1. I first see is a high-pass passive RC filter leading into an active filter. But on reflection, this is really just a DC-blocking filter with a necessary galvanic connection to ground on the other side of the capacitor. Assuming for a moment that the impedance of \$Z_{C_{13}}\ll R_{12}\$ (by at least a factor of 10), I find that anything above about \$16\:\text{Hz}\$ is passed through this filter.
2. I then see what is probably a 2nd order low-pass filter, but that includes a stabilizing capacitor across the feedback resistor, \$R_{20}\$. If that's correct, then I expect to find that the time constant formed by \$C_{19}\$ and \$R_{20}\$ will be somewhat shorter than what is implied from the 2nd order \$\omega_{_0}\$.
3. I then see a low-pass passive RC filter at the output of the active filter. I expect to see the time constant formed by \$C_{1}\$ and \$R_{14}\$ will be a factor of 10 longer than the 2nd order \$\omega_{_0}\$ of the active filter preceding it.

I've no idea how this works out in practice. But that is what I'd expect to see, should I imagine a *"rational designer"* created the circuit.

Let's see.

### Input stage: Passive RC high-pass

The time constant is \$1\:\text{s}\$, which implies \$f\approx 160\:\text{mHz}\$. Given the following \$R_{12}=10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, and expecting that the impedance from \$C_{13}\$ is less than \$\frac1{10}\$th of that, From this, I find that everything near, or more than, about \$160\:\text{Hz}\$ is readily passed through to the active filter.

Here, \$R_{16}\$ is just a necessary galvanic connection for the opposite end of \$C_{13}\$, which must have a discharge/charge path available to it.

There will be some loss for lower frequencies. Say, starting at about \$16\:\text{Hz}\$ and below that.

### Middle stage: Active 2nd order?

The time constant for \$C_{19}\$ and \$R_{20}\$ is \$100\:\mu\text{s}\$. (Or, about \$1.6\:\text{kHz}\$.)

Setting this aside for a moment, and treating the active stage as 2nd order, I find \$\omega_{_0}\approx 960 \:\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{s}}\$ or \$f_{_0}\approx 153\:\text{Hz}\$.

So this implies that \$C_{19}\$ is only there for stabilization and can be ignored in analysis. The middle stage really is a 2nd order stage that loads the input source at about \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$.

### Final stage: Passive RC low-pass

The time constant is \$1.65\:\text{ms}\$, which implies \$f\approx 100\:\text{Hz}\$

### Summary

At a guess, I'd say that this filter system has a roll-off at about \$100\:\text{Hz}\$, at about 3 times \$20\:\text{dB}\$ per decade, or around \$60\:\text{dB}\$ per decade on the high end.

You can see that there was a *rational designer* operating here. The first stage is a high-pass starting with frequencies about an order of magnitude lower than the middle stage's low-pass roll-off and the final stage's low-pass roll-off is about an order of magnitude lower than the middle stage's roll-off.

It's pretty much something one might do *"off the cuff,"* so to speak. You have a mild band-pass formed by the 1st and last passive stages, with a much sharper high-end roll-off contributed by the 2nd order middle stage's active low-pass. The middle stage is active, not passive, and doesn't load the 1st stage (much) while also providing voltage gain. The added \$C_{19}\$ ensures, without otherwise much interfering with the main purposes of the middle stage, that the noise gain is reduced.

> The analysis may be less handy with using some simulators.

There's no need, in this case anyway, for a simulator to perform the analysis for you. It can be done on paper. (Besides, it's better to be able to do things, yourself, and not depend upon tools that you may not have available when you need to be able to think about something.)

That said, here's what LTspice suggests:

[image]

That's surprisingly close to prediction from theory.

The gain is as expected: \$1+\frac{R_{20}}{R_9}\approx 13.2\$ or \$\approx 22.5\:\text{dB}\$.

Comment: well done and really nice formulated! +1

Comment: For fun, tried an "old" LF13741 ... after 10 kHz ... below -120 dB.

Comment: @jonk Did you import a library from the third party of the manufacturer to LTspice with this simulation? I am struggling to do the simulation. Could you please tell me more about the details? I even raised that question in StackExchange. Sorry, I am quite new to LTspice.

Comment: @TSLee No, I didn't bother going off to find a .LIB or .MOD (or whatever) for the opamp you are specifying. The whole purpose of writing the above answer was to point out that you can *ignore* opamp limitations as a necessary simplification for basic analysis and that this is always a good idea. You can add in limitations (such as a GBW of only 155 kHz) as an added bonus, later. So, in choosing a model for the above LTspice run I used the LT1800, which is rail to rail and has a GBW of 80 MHz and then only plotted out to 10 kHz, above, more consistent with your opamp limits.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken the liberty to redraw your circuit using CircuitLab. The frequency sweep is then a click away. Here's the amplitude frequency response of the filter:

[image: Amplitude frequency response of the filter]

Comment: Does CircuitLab support faster opamps? That looks like ~10 MHz compensated unity-gain opamp. Can you try something else that's faster and/or compensated for gain > 1? (Like an LT1800 rail to rail, 80 MHz GBW, or similar?) I'm curious about the part that is above 30 kHz there.